# How do I get the str.center function to print in the middle of the terminal window

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

Im making a python script that would mimic a RobCO Termlink from the Fallout series.
I'm trying to figure out a way to make a loading screen that would display right in the center of the terminal window

I tried a solution I found from a post from about 8 years ago, and got the columns working, but when I try to modify that to do the lines, it gives a type error. I looked it up and saw that the str.center() function I was looking at only had 1 int value, and then a variable for the character to use as filler.

What I tried to use
`print("WELCOME TO ROBCO INDUSTRIES (TM) TERMLINK") print("▓".center(columns, lines)) time.sleep(delay) clear.clear()`

I know you can probably do what I am trying to do with curses, but I'm on Windows and unsure how to set up the windows ports.

Comment: If the terminal has 2n+1 rows, print n blank lines, then the string centered horizontally and then n blank lines again.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so I believe I have a solution that put as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil
from Lib.clear import clear 
input("Press Enter to start")
clear.clear()
columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
lines = shutil.get_terminal_size().lines
print(columns)
print(lines)
input()
clear.clear()
middle = int((lines / 2)-2)
print("\n"*middle)
print("This is the middle of the terminal window".center(columns))
input()
clear.clear()
input("Now hit enter after maximizing the window")
clear.clear()
columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
lines = shutil.get_terminal_size().lines
print(columns)
print(lines)
input()
clear.clear()
middle = int((lines / 2)-2)
print("\n"*middle)
print("This is now the middle of the terminal window".center(columns))
input()
exit()
```

So, based off what @mkreiger1 said, this script finds the center of the window, both column and lines, and then prints those out, and then prints a string at the middle of the terminal

Its not the most optimized way of doing it, but it gets the job done for now.